# How do I enter BIOS

Tags: bios

When I press the <kbd>F2</kbd> key I can enter into BIOS before I change its OS (Windows 7) to Ubuntu in my Samsung 530U3C Ultrabook.

But now I can't, it directly goes to Ubuntu.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't think the BIOS gives you the options which OS to boot, but allows you which device to boot instead.

Comment: I can't answer this question because it's closed but I have a solution that is not hardware-dependent, open this question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As soon as you power on your pc start tapping the keys untill you enter BIOS, for example:

`Power on pc, start tapping F2 until you enter BIOS`

If that doesn't work, try the same procedure but with F1, then ESC, F12.

You should really look into your PC manual to see what is the key for entering BIOS, for some computers it can be F2, for others ESC, etc.

But if you're not sure, just try the method i told you

Comment: I'm trying this, but it not working.

When I power on my pc, its appear left bottom corner show press f2 entry bios or press f4 to recover system but its break, because I reinstall.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you power on the pc and hit F2 many times quickly it should enter in BIOS. By the way you want to enter BIOS for what?

Comment: I want to re-install Ubuntu OS.

I tried these keys, but its not working.

Comment: You don't have to enter BIOS to reinstall Ubuntu, simply boot your pc from a cd/dvd drive or usb drive and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: That's good. Thx @LnxSlck

Comment: eh, didn't set the BIOS to let pc boot from USB/CD/DVD ?

Comment: First you should try to boot an Ubuntu instalation CD/DD see if that works. If  not try booting your pc and tapping F8 or F11 key, to see if a Boot Menu appears

Comment: I just not tried A~Z keys. 
Eh, This laptop hasn't DVD driver  :(

Can I use wubi to re-install and partition ?

Comment: They keys should be F1 to F12 or ESC, but yes you can use Wubi

Comment: Okay, Thx LnSlck.

Answer (score 1):

The key doesn't depend on the OS you have installed, I think. Maybe you pressed F2 at the wrong point of time.

Comment: But how do I resolve it.