# How do I enter the BIOS/UEFI from Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

Windows 10 has a feature to enter BIOS/UEFI directly from the OS, which is handy for machines that do not allow you to enter them during startup.

I would like to install Ubuntu on an OEM device and obviously I will be using the Windows feature to do this, but I will still require BIOS access in the future.

How can I access the BIOS from Ubuntu?

Comment: You can enter UEFI form grub menu.

Comment: You can access it just when your PC starts. [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180244/how-do-i-enter-bios) [link2](https://superuser.com/questions/1076717/how-do-i-boot-to-bios-directly-from-ubuntu)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/318796/when-trying-to-enter-bios-gnu-grub-screen-appears Also can we get make and model # of this machine that doesn't allow BIOS access at boot time?

Comment: `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` but this is not available on all systems. I hope I understood your question right.

Answer (score 9):

The BIOS/UEFI can be accessed by pressing the appropriate key at boot time. A table of BIOS/UEFI access keys for different motherboard manufacturers is in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority/1084586#1084586).

You can also enter the BIOS/UEFI directly from Ubuntu the way you can do sometimes from Windows by running `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` but I strongly recommend that Ubuntu users shouldn't use this method except for when all other methods of accessing the UEFI settings have failed. When I tried this command it reset the CMOS and all my UEFI settings got reset back to their default values including the clock. When I exited from the UEFI settings to reboot, the screen froze and I had to manually power off the computer and cold start it. Fortunately I knew my previous UEFI settings, so I could immediately restore them before exiting from the UEFI settings.

This is what `man systemctl` has to say about the `--firmware-setup` option.

```
--firmware-setup
    When used with the reboot command, indicate to the system's firmware to  
    reboot into the firmware setup interface. Note that this functionality 
    is not available on all systems.
```

`man systemctl` didn't say anything about resetting the CMOS. It only said "this functionality is not available on all systems".

Comment: There is no "appropriate key" on this device

Comment: @ChadWarden *Most* BIOS/UEFI setup utilities can be accessed by pressing the appropriate access key at boot time. I edited my answer with my reply.

Comment: You can enter the BIOS/UEFI directly from Ubuntu by running the command `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` which reboots the machine into BIOS/UEFI. Now I cannot confirm whether it works on all UEFI enabled devices but it did work on all devices I tested.

Comment: @Gecko I strongly recommend that Ubuntu users shouldn't run `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` except for when all other methods of accessing the UEFI settings fail. When I tried this command it reset all my UEFI settings back to their default values including the clock. When I exited from the UEFI settings to reboot, the screen froze and I had to manually power off the computer and cold start it.

Comment: Can't say my experience was the same. For me all setting stayed untouched. The experience was 1:1 the same as using the "Reboot to UEFI/BIOS" functionality on Windows. Considering that resetting BIOS entries is not mentioned in the man page, it could be that this failure is limited to your specific setup.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 20.04 opening a terminal and running

```
sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

worked for me and rebooted me into the UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: On 20.04, I think the answer would be to just show the grub menu and access the "System Setup" menu option, which will take you to UEFI.... The original question doesn't have a version, but this question is dated 2019. The feature is there in 2018...