# VAIO Change boot order to usb from Ubuntu 18.04 to install Windows

Tags: boot, vaio, boot-order

I have a VAIO laptop SVF14212sg(broke screen and cable unplugged) with external monitor and keyboard.
I'm trying to install Windows 10 through bootable usb but i can't access BIOS to change the boot order.
I can boot to the only installed OS Ubuntu.
**Is there a way to change boot order from ubuntu?**
This is what I've tried but so far didn't work, PC turned on but nothing happened in external monitor
a. press ASSIST button when PC off
b. press F2 after power button
c. remove HDD and plug bootable USB to force boot from USB
d. remove and replace CMOS battery
e. change boot order from terminal using efibootmgr but when I restart it still boot to Ubuntu

Comment: I don't see anything on-topic in your question, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is EOSS & thus off-topic on this site **unless** your question is specific to moving to a fully supported release of Ubuntu; your question is mostly about *firmware* issues, and the only other OS you mention (windows) is likewise off-topic. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: FYI:  It is possible (*but **not** advised*) to change some BIOS/firmware settings from a running OS, but those changes will be specific to the actual firmware you're machine uses, and can potentially *brick* the device if operated on the wrong device, ie. you mention VIAO, you'll need to use specific code to be successful (*firmware specific which may include what revisions you've applied to that firmware - thus be careful; make/model isn't sufficient detail*).  I have changed BIOS settings on some devices (usually thinkpads, also dell) with  dead screens, but how is very device specific

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enter the BIOS/UEFI from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1166120/)